# Two geom_line()s with an y-axis each

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I want to make a plot of a time series of two variables -- but the two of them have very different scales. So I want to plot one line following the scale of the left y-axis (say, in millions) and the other line following the secondary right y-axis (in a low percentage scale). Does anybody know how to make it? I have already achieved to put the two y-axis scales as I wish, but I need one of the lines (one of the two variables plotted) to follow the y-axis on the right. Here's some piece of code. It's not super tidy yet but for the sake of my purpose it should work.

```
europe_data %>% 
  rename(`Inflation Rate` = EA19CPALTT01GYM,
         `Money Supply` = MYAGM2EZM196N) %>% 
  mutate(`Inflation Rate` = (`Inflation Rate` * 100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DATE)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `Inflation Rate`),
                linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(aes(y = `Money Supply`)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Inflation Rate",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 1000000000000,
                                         name = "Money Supply"))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you maybe a solution using `base`. You can use this code:

First I created a sample dataset:

```
europe_data <- data.frame(EA19CPALTT01GYM= c(0.1, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1),
                          MYAGM2EZM196N = c(1000000000000, 1102010000200, 1040000607000, 1200030000000, 1000040507808, 1304006060300),
                          DATE = seq(0, 5, 1))
```

After that you can use this code:

```
europe_data <- europe_data %>% 
  rename(`Inflation Rate` = EA19CPALTT01GYM,
         `Money Supply` = MYAGM2EZM196N) %>% 
  mutate(`Inflation Rate` = (`Inflation Rate` * 100))

par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 3, new=TRUE)
## Plot first set of data and draw its axis
plot(europe_data$DATE, europe_data$`Inflation Rate`, pch=16, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,200), xlab="", ylab="", 
     type="b",col="black", main="Your title")
axis(2, ylim=c(0,200),col="black",las=1)  ## las=1 makes horizontal labels
mtext("Inflation rate",side=2,line=2.5)
box()

## Allow a second plot on the same graph
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 3, new=TRUE)
#par(new=TRUE)

## Plot the second plot and put axis scale on right
plot(europe_data$DATE, europe_data$`Money Supply`, pch=15,  xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(0,1300000000000), 
     axes=FALSE, type="b", col="red")
## a little farther out (line=4) to make room for labels
mtext("Money supply",side=4,col="red",line=4) 
axis(4, ylim=c(0,1300000000000), col="red",col.axis="red",las=1)

## Draw the time axis
axis(1,pretty(range(europe_data$DATE),10))
mtext("Date",side=1,col="black",line=2.5)  

## Add Legend
legend("bottomright",legend=c("Inflation rate","Money supply"),
       text.col=c("black","red"),pch=c(16,15),col=c("black","red"))
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When creating a plot with a second axis, you need to remember that the axis is only there "for decoration". Adding a secondary axis doesn't mean the data will both appear on the same scale. You need to modify the *data* that is represented on the second axis too, so that it is at approximately the same scale as the data represented on the first axis. Here, your inflation data is in the range of about -1 to 4, but your money supply is about 5 to 12 trillion. You therefore need to divide the money supply by about 5 trillion (2 * 10^13) to get it on the same scale as the inflation. Then, whatever you have done to the data, you reverse on the secondary axis. Because these numbers are so large, and difficult for people to read easily, I would actually just multiply by 5 instead of 5 trillion, and label the axis as showing trillions:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

europe_data %>% 
  rename(`Inflation Rate` = EA19CPALTT01GYM,
         `Money Supply` = MYAGM2EZM196N) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DATE)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `Inflation Rate`),
                linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(aes(y = `Money Supply` / (5 * 10^12))) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Inflation Rate",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 5,
                                         name = "Money Supply (trillions)"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data**

```r
europe_data <-
  structure(list(DATE = structure(c(9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 
10013, 10043, 10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 
10286, 10317, 10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 
10561, 10592, 10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 
10835, 10865, 10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 
11109, 11139, 11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 11354, 
11382, 11413, 11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 11627, 
11657, 11688, 11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 11839, 11869, 11900, 
11931, 11961, 11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 
12204, 12234, 12265, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 
12478, 12509, 12539, 12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 
12753, 12784, 12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 
13027, 13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 
13300, 13330, 13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 
13573, 13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 
13848, 13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 
14123, 14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 
14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 
14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 
14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 
15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 
15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 
15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 
16040, 16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 
16314, 16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 
16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 
16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 
17136, 17167, 17198, 17226), class = "Date"), MYAGM2EZM196N = c(3.499192e+12, 
3.493103e+12, 3.500177e+12, 3.498558e+12, 3.516345e+12, 3.549216e+12, 
3.54237e+12, 3.531781e+12, 3.543278e+12, 3.555327e+12, 3.587644e+12, 
3.687146e+12, 3.658509e+12, 3.660611e+12, 3.666889e+12, 3.698172e+12, 
3.727306e+12, 3.758294e+12, 3.725595e+12, 3.718421e+12, 3.725841e+12, 
3.740075e+12, 3.789869e+12, 3.920142e+12, 3.95326e+12, 3.911195e+12, 
3.929382e+12, 3.950654e+12, 3.979502e+12, 4.005344e+12, 4.021979e+12, 
3.991118e+12, 4.000412e+12, 4.019772e+12, 4.049147e+12, 4.142298e+12, 
4.137751e+12, 4.133651e+12, 4.143894e+12, 4.186038e+12, 4.177617e+12, 
4.186421e+12, 4.184938e+12, 4.176869e+12, 4.1825e+12, 4.187284e+12, 
4.210799e+12, 4.29963e+12, 4.348576e+12, 4.355581e+12, 4.38508e+12, 
4.422968e+12, 4.445379e+12, 4.492195e+12, 4.479923e+12, 4.461073e+12, 
4.508739e+12, 4.512933e+12, 4.565041e+12, 4.684363e+12, 4.655663e+12, 
4.644451e+12, 4.670235e+12, 4.706318e+12, 4.728195e+12, 4.768158e+12, 
4.758307e+12, 4.750263e+12, 4.792133e+12, 4.811015e+12, 4.875496e+12, 
4.981449e+12, 4.923614e+12, 4.951523e+12, 5.006352e+12, 5.052347e+12, 
5.109432e+12, 5.130101e+12, 5.124234e+12, 5.125966e+12, 5.136978e+12, 
5.157878e+12, 5.206044e+12, 5.297999e+12, 5.271712e+12, 5.273548e+12, 
5.310219e+12, 5.344467e+12, 5.377365e+12, 5.408012e+12, 5.42844e+12, 
5.397916e+12, 5.451083e+12, 5.490285e+12, 5.528865e+12, 5.632265e+12, 
5.637298e+12, 5.643364e+12, 5.680387e+12, 5.738282e+12, 5.778327e+12, 
5.858475e+12, 5.896526e+12, 5.859423e+12, 5.939643e+12, 5.976941e+12, 
6.002366e+12, 6.168737e+12, 6.134008e+12, 6.157331e+12, 6.212517e+12, 
6.316677e+12, 6.321177e+12, 6.386776e+12, 6.382249e+12, 6.360016e+12, 
6.461105e+12, 6.472185e+12, 6.535927e+12, 6.743791e+12, 6704078690000, 
6707663590000, 6830308980000, 6875257540000, 6928872610000, 7023576910000, 
7063718310000, 7044759300000, 7140136020000, 7229789160000, 7288789240000, 
7436873890000, 7449456190000, 7471674820000, 7544870830000, 7625570920000, 
7688719570000, 7734626560000, 7750323860000, 7759475670000, 7839898820000, 
7.972122e+12, 8018985080000, 8103056980000, 8101892210000, 8093799240000, 
8094023230000, 8164981320000, 8157431590000, 8186152570000, 8170120430000, 
8152961550000, 8153645390000, 8178413500000, 8169984240000, 8275090590000, 
8234925070000, 8210916120000, 8209451530000, 8268951740000, 8301215080000, 
8333155330000, 8337672910000, 8342473540000, 8344372870000, 8378476210000, 
8388300570000, 8472295450000, 8435754600000, 8415889110000, 8441078810000, 
8482013950000, 8488118150000, 8517982800000, 8522260990000, 8530699180000, 
8568031090000, 8555869480000, 8565193560000, 8.670606e+12, 8.64011e+12, 
8.648411e+12, 8.718042e+12, 8.721253e+12, 8.752512e+12, 8.810355e+12, 
8.833836e+12, 8.82621e+12, 8.866345e+12, 8.928497e+12, 8.955965e+12, 
9.044639e+12, 9.017783e+12, 9.052631e+12, 9.081338e+12, 9.103737e+12, 
9.1284e+12, 9.129744e+12, 9.157419e+12, 9.185109e+12, 9.179608e+12, 
9.218195e+12, 9.236345e+12, 9.212147e+12, 9.24422e+12, 9.272606e+12, 
9.27787e+12, 9.289816e+12, 9.328806e+12, 9.355707e+12, 9.393273e+12, 
9.44385e+12, 9.475081e+12, 9.497903e+12, 9.569281e+12, 9.668681e+12, 
9.749062e+12, 9.764289e+12, 9.810907e+12, 9.859662e+12, 9.914221e+12, 
9.946958e+12, 1.0011211e+13, 1.0037605e+13, 1.0068328e+13, 1.0124772e+13, 
1.01861e+13, 1.0215459e+13, 1.0274065e+13, 1.0312438e+13, 1.0348009e+13, 
1.0376779e+13, 1.0416638e+13, 1.0457644e+13, 1.0512054e+13, 1.0547979e+13, 
1.0573312e+13, 1.0590298e+13, 1.0667463e+13, 1.0686288e+13, 1.0744692e+13, 
1.079786e+13, 1.0876141e+13), EA19CPALTT01GYM = c(2.2, 2, 1.7, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.8, 1.6, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.1, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8, 1, 1.1, 1, 0.9, 
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 1.8, 1.9, 2.2, 2.2, 
2.1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.6, 2.1, 2.1, 2.3, 2.8, 3.1, 2.9, 2.6, 2.4, 
2.3, 2.3, 2, 2.1, 2.6, 2.5, 2.5, 2.4, 2.1, 1.9, 2, 2.2, 2.1, 
2.3, 2.3, 2.3, 2.2, 2.4, 2.4, 2.1, 1.9, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.1, 
2.2, 2, 1.8, 1.7, 1.7, 2.1, 2.5, 2.4, 2.3, 2.4, 2.2, 2.4, 2.3, 
2.4, 1.9, 2.1, 2.2, 2.1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.6, 2.5, 2.3, 2.3, 
2.5, 2.4, 2.2, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.3, 1.8, 1.6, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 
1.9, 2, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 1.8, 2.2, 2.6, 3.1, 3.1, 3.3, 3.3, 
3.7, 3.3, 3.7, 4, 4.1, 3.9, 3.7, 3.2, 2.2, 1.7, 1.2, 1.2, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.1, -0.1, -0.6, -0.1, -0.3, -0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 1.6, 
1.6, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.6, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.7, 2.8, 
2.7, 2.7, 2.6, 2.6, 3, 3, 3, 2.8, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.6, 2.4, 2.4, 
2.4, 2.6, 2.6, 2.5, 2.2, 2.2, 2, 1.9, 1.7, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.6, 
1.3, 1.1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.3, -0.2, -0.6, -0.3, -0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 
0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, -0.1, 0, -0.3, -0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 
0.5, 0.6, 1.1, 1.7, 2, 1.5)), row.names = 205:447, class = "data.frame")
```